# Ratios/Percentages in R Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, markerclusterer

I am trying to display percentages on a Leaflet Cluster Map using R.

For example:

The quakes data set in Leaflet looks like this:

```
head(quakes)

     lat   long depth mag stations
1 -20.42 181.62   562 4.8       41
2 -20.62 181.03   650 4.2       15
3 -26.00 184.10    42 5.4       43
4 -17.97 181.66   626 4.1       19
5 -20.42 181.96   649 4.0       11
6 -19.68 184.31   195 4.0       12
```

I create a cluster map with the leaflet package with the following code:

```
leaflet(quakes) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
```

The code renders a map with clusters and uses the counts as labels.

ClusterMap Example:

[image]

How would I go about using the average of the 'mag' column as a label for my clusters? I still want the ability to zoom in and out of the map.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: this might help https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#customising-the-clustered-markers